# How to update the quantity of all items in the cart with respect to database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am doing a shopping cart using code-igniter. While I can do the add cart functions, I'm somewhat confused with how to update them with regards to database. All I want is when I change the item quantity in the cart and click update ,both the cart and database must be updated for that particular item.I tried to do it but couldn't get it.Can someone please enlighten me what to do?

controller code

```
 $this->load->model('user_m');
    $result['query'] = $this->user_m->get($id); // inserts coresponing item
    foreach ($result['query'] as $row) 

        $id = $row->pid;
        $qty = $a;
        $quan=$row->quantity;
        $price = $row->pprice;
    $name = $row->pname;

    $q=$quan-$a;     // for remainig stock i.e total qty-user qty
        $data = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'qty' => $qty,
        'price' => $price,
        'name' => $name,
        'stock' =>$q
    ); 
    $this->cart->insert($data);

    $this->load->model('user_m');
    $result['qry'] = $this->user_m->up_cart($id,$q);
   redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); 

}
```

just tell me how to update pls!

Comment: Have you get any error???

Comment: I re-edited so its not complete.I just need to know how to update them in controller.

Answer (score 0):

when ever you add any product in cart, it will generate an uniq row ID and that will be unique for each and every product and hence you need to update quantity by that row ID

```
       $data = array(
           'rowid' => 'b99ccdf16028f015540f341130b6d8ec',
           'qty'   => 3
        );

      $this->cart->update($data);
```

// Or a multi-dimensional array

```
       $data = array(
           array(
                   'rowid'   => 'b99ccdf16028f015540f341130b6d8ec',
                   'qty'     => 3
                ),
           array(
                   'rowid'   => 'xw82g9q3r495893iajdh473990rikw23',
                   'qty'     => 4
                ),
           array(
                   'rowid'   => 'fh4kdkkkaoe30njgoe92rkdkkobec333',
                   'qty'     => 2
                )
        );

      $this->cart->update($data);
```

Now you want to know about how you will get row id.

```
      $cart=$this->cart->contents();
```

it will return whole array of cart and when you listing it on webpage, please associate row id with quantity text box to update that particular product.

please check following url:

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to update a particular product from cart to database? I can't seem to fetch them on my controller.